# how to know current buffer have set-mark

Tags: emacs, elisp

is there any way know there is set-mark beginning and where is the start point query in lisp

Comment: could you clarify what you need this for? programming an ELISP script? or for using Emacs?

Comment: personally I just want single key binding for different usage which depend on mark-active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the variable `mark-active`:

```
mark-active is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is nil
Local in buffer whole-line-or-region.el; global value is nil

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set in any fashion.

Documentation:
Non-nil means the mark and region are currently active in this buffer.
```

You might also want to check if mark === point, if it's really a region you're looking for:

```
(if (and mark-active
    (/= (point) (mark)))
```

If you want to write a function that requires a region be defined, you can use `interactive`, like so:

```
(defun my-fn-that-requires-a-region (beg end)
  "Some documentation string mentioning BEG and END."
  (interactive "r")
  (message "%d / %d" beg end))
```

If called interactively, mark must be set or an error is generated.  Called programatically, any two values must be passed in; no validation of the parameters is done.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend turning on `transient-mark-mode`

```
(setq transient-mark-mode t)
```

`transient-mark-mode` will highlight the region between the mark and your current point.

Alternatively, you can press `C-x C-x` to jump between the current point and the mark to see where the mark is set.

Comment: thanks Ryan, how programming in lisp to know mark-mode is mark now